# asp.net server tags not resolving before being sent to client

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I have a WebForms site which is experiencing issues. Looking in Firebug, I can see that the following line in my master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("/css/site.css") %>' />
```

is not "executing" on the server. Therefore, in Firebug I am getting:

> http://www.mysite.com/Master_Pages/%3C%25=%20ResolveClientUrl(%22/css/site.css%22)%20%25%3E

when I would expect this to be

> http://www.mysite.com/css/site.css

This has worked fine previously, and i've used this technique on other sites and never had a problem, but can't see why this has suddenly stopped working.
I've double checked and my head is set to runat=server:

`<head runat="server">`

so it should be executing on the server. 
I've also tried changing it to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=<%= ResolveClientUrl("/css/site.css") %> runat="server" />
```

Other things I've checked:

- That the application pool and website are both targeting the correct and same instance of the .net framework
- That the application pool has been recycled to ensure its clear
- That I can hit break-points in my code behind

Can anyone suggest what may be causing this or what things I can check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" />
```

This should work.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, it produces http://www.mysite.com/Master_Pages/css/site.css

Comment: Instead try <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" />. this should work. It works my side.

Comment: That will fix CSS links, but script links dont work then. Plus its masking the problem rather than solving it...

Comment: You also need to change Script links same as css.

Answer (score 0):

`ResolveClientUrl("/css/site.css")` should be `ResolveClientUrl("~/css/site.css")`

and also you omitted quotes around the value of attribute `href`.